# Why are normal and applicative order evaluation named as such?

Tags: functional-programming, terminology, interpreter, evaluation, lambda-calculus

While I somewhat understand the differences between the two methods of evaluation, I am trying to understand the meaning inherent in their names. Why name it 'normal' order, what norm is being adhered to (if the question makes any sense)? The term 'applicative' makes sense in that it describes a practical method for evaluating an expression, as opposed to the 'normal' one, but who would think of using normal order first? References to the person or people who named these terms and their rationale will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [normal order normalizes terms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduction_strategy#Lambda_calculus)

Comment: Thank you for the reference, it makes much more sense to me now.